# Disabling input field (submit button) doesnt work with jquery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html form:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<input id="one_click_button" class="global-button" type="submit" value="Send"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And none of the below works:

```
$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
$("#one_click_button").attr("disabled","disabled");
$(':submit').attr("disabled", true);
$('#one_click_button').attr("disabled", true);
```

I have jquery 1.7 on my site, and tried to make it work on http://jsfiddle.net with jquery 1.7.1. Can someone help me to find, what is the problem with this versions (other work properly).

Comment: Code is fine, the problem is somewhere else. DOM ready?

Comment: It works properly on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amaNG/1/) with `jQuery 1.6.4 and 1.7.2`

Comment: Post your full code or make a fiddle of non working.

Answer (score 2):

@Artem, Your code is fine, but it depends how you want your button be disabled. To disable using CSS(Your code):

http://jsfiddle.net/L3G78/

Or you can use disabled attribute of HTML as:

```
<input id="one_click_button" disabled class="global-button" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

or

```
<input id="one_click_button" disabled=disabled class="global-button" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Comment: The link is to jquery 1.7.2, that is a major problem! It doesn`t work on 1.7 or 1.7.1

Comment: Then you can use the HTML version. It is browser dependent.

Comment: but i need flexibility of js))

Comment: Then Why can't you update jquery version of yours ??

Comment: Because its huge site with different librarys, i update jquery and other functions stop working.

Comment: The above fiddle is working with jquery 1.6.4 as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code...

`$( "#one_click_button" ).prop( "disabled", true );`

Answer (score 0):

Its working for `$('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);`

```
                   <form>
                    <fieldset>
                     <input id="one_click_button" class="global-button" type="submit" value="Send"/>
                   </fieldset>
                  </form>
```

and jquery --

```
              $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
```

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9TQBq/1/)

Comment: Yes, I've updated the fiddle with Jquery 1.7.1, its still working, check